# JComboBox and Action, New Model etc

Tags: java, swing, events, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have something weird that i cant understand why its happening.
I searched the web including here but couldn't find an answer.
I have 3 ComboBox that 2 followed by one.
It a applet convert tool.
Every time that i choose the field i want to convert at the Main ComboBox its loading the other two with the values to convert. But after its load every time i'm making a selection of what i want to convert its effecting both of ComboBox.
This is the code : 
        // This is the Objects //////

```
     MyEvent handler = new MyEvent();

    MainCombo = new JComboBox(issueArray);
    MainCombo.setBounds(120, 50, 120, 20);
    MainCombo.addActionListener(handler);
    add(MainCombo);

    Combo1 = new JComboBox(Angle);
    Combo1.setBounds(120, 90, 120, 20);
    Combo1.addActionListener(handler);
    add(Combo1);

    Combo2 = new JComboBox(Angle);
    Combo2.setBounds(320, 90, 120, 20);
    Combo2.addActionListener(handler);
    add(Combo2);

    //The Method To Change Values In The ComboBox 
     public void loadIssueParam(String Issue){
    Combo1.removeAllItems();
    Combo2.removeAllItems();
    switch (Issue) {
        case "Angle":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Angle);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Area":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel   newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Area);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Data":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel  newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Data);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Energy":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel   newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Energy);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Force":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel      newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Force);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Length":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel      newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Length);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Mass":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel        newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Mass);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Power":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel       newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Power);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Pressure":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel  newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Pressure);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Speed":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel  newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Speed);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Temperature":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel  newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Temperature);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Time":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel  newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Time);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
        case "Volume":
            {
                DefaultComboBoxModel newModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(Volume);
                Combo1.setModel(newModel);
                Combo2.setModel(newModel);
                break;
            }
    }

    /// I THINK MAYBE THIS METHOD HAVE SOMETHING TO DO WITH IT - OR I NEED SOME HOW TO
    /// CLEAR THE SELECTION.



      private class MyEvent implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if(event.getSource()==MainCombo){
        JComboBox cb=(JComboBox)event.getSource();
        IssueBox=(String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        loadIssueParam(IssueBox);
    } 
        if(event.getSource()==Combo1){
        JComboBox cb=(JComboBox)event.getSource();
        fromBox=(String)cb.getSelectedItem();
    } 
        if(event.getSource()==Combo2){
        JComboBox cb=(JComboBox)event.getSource();
        toBox=(String)cb.getSelectedItem();
    }
    }
}
```

EVERY TIME THAT I MAKE A SUB SELECTION ITS EFFECTING BOTH SUB COMBOBOX.

Thanks for the help
   Niro

Comment: Could you post all the code so one can actually run it and reproduce this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I understand your problem now after looking at your code. Your problem is that both sub-comboboxes share the same model, and so if you change the selection in one sub-combo box, it changes the state of the shared model, causing the other sub-combo box to change its selection.. To solve your problem, give each of them their own model.

i.e.,

```
switch (Issue) {
    case "Angle":
        {
            DefaultComboBoxModel newModel1 = new DefaultComboBoxModel(Angle);
            DefaultComboBoxModel newModel2 = new DefaultComboBoxModel(Angle);
            Combo1.setModel(newModel1);
            Combo2.setModel(newModel2);
            break;
        }
    // etc...
```

Also, consider using a Map such as a `HashMap<String, String[]>` or `HashMap<String, Vector<String>>`.  Do this and fill the Map up correctly, and that huge switch statement could be simplified to

```
Combo1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(modelMap.get(Issue)));
Combo2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(modelMap.get(Issue)));
```

And next we'll work on Java naming rules.

Comment: Thank you So Much. Fix the problem ! I'll actually try to do it with the HashMap - Seems like way cleaner solution. Thanks Again